# Reading data from a SharePoint list

Tags: list, web-part

I have a SharePoint list I would like to read data from and show it on labels that are on web part.

Can anyone help me with the C# code I should use? My list name is Leave Request

Answer (score 0):

You can get SharePoint List items using this code:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Leave Request");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
            "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
//You can add here logic to add data in Label
    }
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956%28v=office.14%29.aspx) You can get reference for it.